# I have downloaded the ethereum blockchain project build in react,solidity,truffle

Tags: reactjs, npm, blockchain, solidity

Now It doesn't run on my ubuntu machine. When I run the `npm start` command it says missing script start. Is there any method to run the downloaded project?

Comment: npm && npm start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `package.json` file, check `scripts` property:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf build/*",
    "copy-assets": "ts-node src/tools/copyAssets",
    "tsc": " tsc",
    "build": "npm-run-all clean tsc copy-assets",
    "dev": "nodemon  --watch src -e ts,ejs,css --exec npm run dev:start",
    "dev:start": "npm-run-all build start",
  },
```

Looks like `start` script does not exist. Instead run the appropriate one from the scripts section.